# Split a log entry in two events with logstash-grok, clone and mutate

Tags: logging, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to split a log in two events with [grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok), [mutate](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate) and [clone](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/clone) in my logstash configuration.
My stack is a very standard [ELK](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elkdownloads/) (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana).

I'm creating a log that is formatted like that :

```
timestamp float integer
```

For instance :

```
2015/01/19 21:48:12 24.7 32
2015/01/19 22:00:20 24.7 32
2015/01/19 22:01:11 24.7 32
2015/01/19 22:01:58 24.7 28
2015/01/19 22:02:28 23.7 28
(etc ...)
```

Eventually, I want two events in logstash, one with the keys `timestamp` obviously, `type=sensorA` and `value=%{the value of the integer}` and another with the same timestamp and `value=%{value of the float}` and `type=sensorB`.

So far, I've come with this configuration in `logstash.conf`:

1.My log is tagged with `type=sensor` in my inputs :

```
  input {
    file {
      path => "/var/log/sensors.log"
      type => "sensor"
    }
  }
```

2.Then, I use grok, clone and mutate to try to split them

```
if [type] == "sensor" {
  # Extracts the values
  grok { 
    match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM:month}/%{MONTHDAY:day} %{TIME}) %{NUMBER:sensorA:float} %{NUMBER:sensorB:int}" }
  }
  mutate {
    update => [ "type", "sensorA" ]
  }
  # Clones the event
  clone {
    clones => ["sensorB"]
  }
}
# So now I should have two events, 
# one with type sensorA and one with type sensorB, no ? :
if [type] == "sensorA" {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "value" => "%{sensorA}" }
    convert => ["value", "float"]
  }
}
if [type] == "sensorB" {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "value" => "%{sensorB}" }
    convert => ["value", "integer"]
  }
}
```

But that doesn't really work, since eventhough I get two events with a different type, they **both have the same value** (which is that of sensorB, always).

How come ? I got a feeling the logstash.conf file is not really read in a linear fashion but I can't find any solution for this.

Any hint? Am I missing something really obvious here ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using mutate to convert the value to `value` field, you can use `ruby` plugin to do what you need.

```
if [type] == "sensor" {
    # Extracts the values
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM:month}/%{MONTHDAY:day} %{TIME}) %{NUMBER:sensorA:float} %{NUMBER:sensorB:int}" }
    }
    mutate {
        update => [ "type", "sensorA" ]
    }
    # Clones the event
    clone {
        clones => ["sensorB"]
    }
}
# So now I should have two events,
# one with type sensorA and one with type sensorB, no ? :
ruby {
    code => "
        if event['type'] == 'sensorA'
                event['value'] = event['sensorA']
        elsif event['type'] == 'sensorB'
                event['value'] = event['sensorB']
        end
    "
}
```

With this config, I can meet your requirement. 
Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Yes, it could work that way, but I still don't get why using `mutate`  doesn't work; It is — I think — exactly equivalent, so it should ...

Comment: I believe the mutate-update should use `=>` instead of a two element array. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-update